# Twitter APIで取得できるツイートは何日前までですか？

Tags: c#, twitter

C#(Core Tweet)を用いてTwitterの検索結果をExcelに出力するツールを作っています。

Twitter APIでは過去１週間のツイートしか取得できないはずですが、10日ほど前のツイートを取得していることが稀にあります。
調べてもそのような記載が見当たらないのですが、なぜなのでしょうか。

[追記]
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。  
こちらのuntilの部分です。  
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

Comment: このサイトでは質問下のコメント欄は質問に対する疑問点や指摘に、回答下のコメント欄は回答に対するコメントや指摘に、と使い分けているので、上のコメントは回答のコメント欄に書いていただいた方がよいかと思います（そうすれば回答者にも通知されますし）。また参考URLなどの補足は、質問を[edit]して書いていただくのも手です。

Comment: unarist様
ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

> Twitter apiでは過去1週間のツイートしか取得できないはずですが

出典がありましたら提示していただきたいです。

---

[GET statuses/home_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline)

> Up to 800 Tweets are obtainable on the home timeline.

ホームタイムラインであれば800件です。

[GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline)

> This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user’s most recent Tweets.

特定のユーザーのツイートであれば3200件です。

Comment: sayuri様
質問に追記しましたURL先に「Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit.」と記載があります。